# R internet routines can't be loaded on an XP SP3 machine

Tags: windows-xp, r

I have installed r in order to be able to perform some statistical tests on some research data that I have. 
My internet connection is OK but whenever I try to install the relevant package or any other package for that matter, I keep getting more or less the same massage:

starting httpd help server ...Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : internet routines cannot be loaded In addition: Warning message: In startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : unable to load shared object 'D:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/modules/i386/internet.dll': LoadLibrary failure: The specified procedure could not be found.

Any help with this will be most appreciated
:-)

Saar

Comment: @dsstorefile, that would make a good answer.

Comment: @dsstorefile, An older version of R may be an answer in this case. Any Idea what is the last XP supported version of R? (There is no specification on the R WIKI)

Comment: If you can run XP, you can run linux..... might not be a bad idea here

Answer (score 2):

As I've mentioned in the comments, R is no longer supported on XP: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f

From the information I can gather from the Internet Archive, version 3.4.0 was the last version to support XP: https://web.archive.org/web/20170627115915/https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html. The next snapshot of the R FAQ shows that version 3.4.1 drops support for XP: https://web.archive.org/web/20170705012731/https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html. This change in OS compatibility occurred between June and July of 2017.

Version 3.4.0 can be downloaded from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.4.0/.

Comment: I'm thanking you for now, will intall it and see. I'll report whether this works or not, thanks again